# Timeout exception in Web Service

Tags: c#, winforms, web-services

I have written a program in c# windows application that calls a web service by creating HttpRequest object and gets the response. Everything was working fine as expected in the development phase but now in User Acceptance Testing, whenever the web service is called it is throwing a timeout exception as I am not getting a response after invoking the web service url. But if I invoke the same url from Fiddler, I am getting an immediate response with 200 status code. Below is the code snippet of my program calling a web service url

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(stWebServiceURI);
request.Method = "GET";
request.ContentType = "text/xml";
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

NOTE: A web service call from my application is not getting logged in Fiddler.

Any help on this is much appreciated. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you try use request.Proxy = null;?

Comment: can your calling host actually reach the server? you can test manually with other types of http clients, perhaps.

Comment: is your app allowed to make requests (firewall) on test env?